# [Python], How to calculate 'service response time' per conversation id

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate the average 'service response time' per conversation id as a variable in a dataframe (in minutes).

The 'service response time' is calculated by the difference between the 'created_at' variable from Y and X in minutes:

X = the **first row** where owner_type == "User" and is_interaction == 1.

Y = the **first row** after X where owner_type == "Agent" and owner_id != 1.

**Update:**

| id | owner_type | owner_id | conversation_id | message | created_at | is_interaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 260943 | Agent | 1 | 26276 | a | 01/03/2022 15:00 |  |
| 265544 | Agent | 1 | 26276 | b | 05/03/2022 12:01 |  |
| 266749 | User | 153263 | 26276 | c | 05/03/2022 15:49 | 1 |
| 266750 | User | 153263 | 26276 | d | 05/03/2022 15:49 | 1 |
| 266753 | Agent | 14 | 26276 | e | 05/03/2022 15:51 |  |
| 267003 | Agent | 1 | 26276 | f | 06/03/2022 12:01 |  |
| 268900 | User | 153263 | 26276 | g | 06/03/2022 17:01 | 1 |
| 268904 | Agent | 1 | 26276 | h | 07/03/2022 12:00 |  |
| 271141 | Agent | 1 | 26276 | i | 09/03/2022 12:00 |  |
| 271725 | User | 153263 | 26276 | j | 09/03/2022 13:01 | 1 |
| 271728 | User | 153263 | 26276 | k | 09/03/2022 13:01 | 1 |
| 271727 | Agent | 10 | 26277 | l | 09/03/2022 13:01 |  |
| 272085 | Agent | 1 | 26276 | m | 10/03/2022 12:01 |  |

Any ideas on how to calculate this?

**Update:**

The resulted output should look like this:

[image]

You should replace the column name "Average Response Time (in minutes)" for "srt" in the dataframe. Ignore the "Average" in this column name, because it's not and the "Date" column if not needed.

Best regards,

Milan Passchier

Comment: How do you know which owner is related to a corresponding user?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand your question. The only relationship between the User and the Agent is that, in normal circumstances, the Agent (where owner_id is not equal to 1) responds to the user.

Comment: The conversation_id does not change, as well as the owner_id where the owner_type is equal to 'User', since it is the users own conversation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 04.11.2022**

If you had a unique ID for each event, then it would be easier. And more: 'X = the first row where owner_type == "User" and is_interaction == 1.' This is not the first row at all, but the last one before 'Y = the first row after X where owner_type == "Agent" and owner_id != 1'.

I offer two options. In both cases, the created_at column is converted to the desired format using pd.to_datetime, and a 'srt' column is created with empty values. Explicit [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc) indexing is used.

In the first one, the main logic is in [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) (they are many times faster than a loop).

**More:**

First, a list **bbb** is created, in which the condition is checked at each iteration:

```
if df.loc[i, 'owner_type'] == 'User' and df.loc[i, 'is_interaction'] == 1
```

if it is met, then the iteration number is written and the **my_func** function is called, which is fed the iteration number and 'conversation_id'. The function takes a dataframe by slice starting from **i** to the last one. Finds a row with 'Agent' that does not equal 1 and has the same 'conversation_id'. The first available line is taken:

```
m = aaa.index[0]
```

If there are no such strings, then the function returns -1.

Thus, we get the list **bbb**, in which the User indexes are on the left and Agent on the right.

In the **fff** list, the last lines where the Agent index stops repeating are copied.

Further in the loop, with the help of the selected indices, the necessary lines are filled using loc.

**code list comprehensions:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], errors='raise')
df['srt'] = np.nan

def my_func(i, id):
    m = -1
    aaa = df[i:]
    aaa = aaa[(df.loc[i:, 'conversation_id'] == id) & (df.loc[i:, 'owner_type'] == 'Agent')
              & (df.loc[i:, 'owner_id'] != 1)]

    if len(aaa) > 0:
        m = aaa.index[0]

    return m


bbb = np.array([[i, my_func(i, df.loc[i, 'conversation_id'])]
                for i in range(len(df)) if df.loc[i, 'owner_type'] == 'User' and df.loc[i, 'is_interaction'] == 1])
fff = [bbb[i] for i in range(len(bbb) - 1) if (bbb[i, 1] != bbb[i + 1:, 1]).all() == True and bbb[i, 1] != -1]

if len(bbb) > 1 and bbb[-1, 1] != -1:
    fff.append(bbb[-1])

fff = np.array(fff)

for i in fff:
    df.loc[i[0], 'srt'] = (df.loc[i[1], 'created_at'] - df.loc[i[0], 'created_at']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')

print(df)
```

The solution is where all the logic is in a loop.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], errors='raise')
df['srt'] = np.nan


ferst_time_user = 0
cid = 0
ind = 0

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'owner_type'] == 'User' and df.loc[i, 'is_interaction'] == 1:
        ferst_time_user = df.loc[i, 'created_at']
        cid = df.loc[i, 'conversation_id']
        ind = i

    if ferst_time_user != 0 and df.loc[i, 'conversation_id'] == cid and df.loc[i, 'owner_type'] == 'Agent' and df.loc[i, 'owner_id'] != 1:
        df.loc[ind, 'srt'] = (df.loc[i, 'created_at'] - ferst_time_user) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')
        ferst_time_user = 0
        ind = 0
        cid = 0

print(df)
```

Output

```
        id owner_type  owner_id  conversation_id message          created_at  \
0   260943      Agent         1            26276       a 2022-01-03 15:00:00   
1   265544      Agent         1            26276       b 2022-05-03 12:01:00   
2   266749       User    153263            26276       c 2022-05-03 15:49:00   
3   266750       User    153263            26276       d 2022-05-03 15:49:00   
4   266753      Agent        14            26276       e 2022-05-03 15:51:00   
5   267003      Agent         1            26276       f 2022-06-03 12:01:00   
6   268900       User    153263            26276       g 2022-06-03 17:01:00   
7   268904      Agent         1            26276       h 2022-07-03 12:00:00   
8   271141      Agent         1            26276       i 2022-09-03 12:00:00   
9   271725       User    153263            26276       j 2022-09-03 13:01:00   
10  271728       User    153263            26276       k 2022-09-03 13:01:00   
11  271727      Agent        10            26277       l 2022-09-03 13:01:00   
12  272085      Agent         1            26276       m 2022-10-03 12:01:00   

    is_interaction  srt  
0              NaN  NaN  
1              NaN  NaN  
2              1.0  NaN  
3              1.0  2.0  
4              NaN  NaN  
5              NaN  NaN  
6              1.0  NaN  
7              NaN  NaN  
8              NaN  NaN  
9              1.0  NaN  
10             1.0  NaN  
11             NaN  NaN  
12             NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Hey, many thanks for helping me out! I will look into this next week

Comment: You are close to the solution, but I would like to store the 'Service Response Time' as a variable in the dataframe (in minutes). Any ideas?

Comment: @MilanPasschier answered see updates. Don't forget to include the module: import numpy as np.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not create a new variable in the dataframe. I want something like df['srt]' with the corresponding 'service response time'.

Comment: @MilanPasschier did as far as I understood you, see the update. If you need something else, then show the expected result to understand exactly what is needed.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this soon! I posted an update where I included an example of the wanted output

Comment: Alright, maybe this could help: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/How-to-calculate-service-response-time-per-conversation-id/m-p/2477803/ . I asked a similar question a couple of months ago (using DAX) on a Power BI forum, but I don't know the solution using Python

Comment: You should get two values judging by the picture. I proceeded that: "the first row where owner_type == "User" and is_interaction == 1" that is, there should be one row. It turns out that starting from id 271725, the operation starts over again?

Comment: Yes, I would like to calculate the difference between the time the user sends a message to the agent and the response to that message by the agent

Comment: After the line: "User" and is_interaction == 1 is the next line always "Agent" and owner_id != 1 or can it appear several lines later?

Comment: @MilanPasschier check the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249292/discussion-between-inquirer-and-milan-passchier).